# WSO2 API Manager: How to listen PassThroughHttpListener on single IP address

Tags: ip, wso2, bind, axis, wso2-esb

When I start the WSO2 AM, I see that AM is listing to all IP-adresses on the server:

```
PassThroughHttpListener Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280
```

I want to bind to a single IP address. IMHO I thing I should change the axis2.xml file? I should change all

```
<transportReceiver name="http"
  class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener">
...
  <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">172.29.4.97</parameter>
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Could you check this link: http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Setting+Up+Host+Names+and+Ports

Comment: Correct! I did that :-) I changed ALL the bind-address parameters, but in the log output I still see [2014-02-06 12:43:41,945]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8243
[2014-02-06 12:43:41,945]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
[2014-02-06 12:43:41,959]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8280

Comment: The bind-address is supported only in previous transport: NHTTP. I couldn't find a way to achieve your requirement in the current pass-through transport.

Comment: Is this a 'bug' or 'feature' that the bind-address is not working for PassThroughHttpListener?

Comment: Looks like the bind-address feature was not implemented for Pass-through transport.

Comment: Created a JIRA issue
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2001

Comment: Thanks Marc! If possible, move the issue to ESBJAVA project as it has to be fixed from ESB side. https://wso2.org/jira/secure/MoveIssue!default.jspa?id=53326 Please provide these details as an answer to this StackOverflow question.

Comment: I am not authorized to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments; Issue is not implemented in PassThrough Listener, issue logged: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-2001